# Need an approach to switch urls if one doesn't work in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

In our project, we are recently setup apis in azure. Earlier the apis were on Mulesoft. So now we were required to call Azure, but in case we are not able to access the newly setup Azure endpoint, we want to connect to the old mule endpoint. Is there any setup in-build in Spring Boot I can make use of? Or should I depend on the code(java) to switch. Just want the best approach on this.

EDIT: I wanted to re-phrase the above question. I wanted to ask is there a possibility to switch between Mule and Azure on the fly(after we deploy the code onto Production).
Answer is YES. We can, as I came across the concept of feature flag. This feature can provide the switch between Mule and Azure and we might not have to do the code changes in case the new endpoint fails.BUT, yes we still have to code to include both conditions.
I am exploring the possibilities, whether to go for Togglz or FF4J library. Which one should be better to be adapted on company level...

Comment: Personally I would approach this with code, but it's personal preference. E.g. when starting your app, send a request to see if the new API is available, then use the old API if the new one is unavailable. You can store the URL as a string somewhere then reuse it throughout your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions in answering this question, the APIs that are deployed in Azure are the same Mulesoft APIs and your deployment strategy has moved to the private cloud using Mule runtime? And by this, you are achieving Active and DR on a hybrid setup for High Availability (HA)?

- In that case, ideally, All you need is a load balancer (preferably a
  Dynamic DNS) that can route between your active and DR. This way as a
  consumer (you as a spring boot developer) need not switch between
  URLs in case of system failures and the LB will handle it
- If the above is not feasible, or if your Azure APIs are getting migrated and the plan is to use Mule as a fallback, then you have to handle this in your code.

Hope this helps,

Comment: second option is what I am aiming to achieve.